# How to trigger an event when something is clicked 5 times?

Tags: c#, events

I know this is probably a stupid question with an easy answer, but I can't figure it out. I'm trying to trigger an event when a label is pressed 5 times. How could I go about doing this?

Comment: It's not a stupid question but a question that you didn't research well. Double click the label and that will create the event handler. In that increase the counter by 1. If it's 5, do whatever and reset it.

Comment: What do I do to increase the counter? I'm extremely confused. @CodingYoshi

Comment: You need a class level variable to do the counting.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, we don't know what label do you use - Windows Forms, Web Forms, WPF? For example, if you use Web Forms, this is completely different story with postbacks etc. WPF is also completely different "animal".

So, if this is a windows forms label or other control, just declare a class-variable/member and do something when it clicked 5 times and then reset it

```
public class Clickable 
{
    private int _counter = 0;


    private void SomeControl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _counter++;
        if (_counter == 5)
        {
            // DO SOMETHING HERE
            MySpecialMethod();
            // And then reset counter so you can click 5 times again
            _counter = 0;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: `System.Windows.Forms.Label` actually does have [Click](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.label?view=netframework-4.8#events) event.

Comment: @CodingYoshi I was actually looking at docs. Fixed. I think, the way docs structured, click is probably inherited from `control`, so it wasn't listed under events menu but it is under "label" menu and in the list. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I know this has been resolved, but I wanted to do the same thing recently and I'd like to share my implementation.

What I wanted was: **do something when the user clicks 5 times within 2 seconds**

Here's my helper class ClickStreakMachine.cs

```cs
using System;

namespace MyApp01;

/// <summary>
/// A helper class that invokes an action when the Click method is triggered enough times within a certain time window
/// </summary>
public class ClickStreakMachine
{
    private readonly int _requiredClicks;
    private readonly TimeSpan _maxClickSpacing;
    private readonly Action _action;

    private DateTime _lastClickedAt = DateTime.MinValue;
    private int _clickStreak = 0;

    /// <summary>
    /// A helper class that invokes an action when the Click method is triggered enough times within a certain time window
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="requiredClicks">Clicks required to trigger the action</param>
    /// <param name="maxClickSpacing">Max distance between clicks</param>
    /// <param name="action">Action to trigger when conditions are met</param>
    public ClickStreakMachine(int requiredClicks, TimeSpan maxClickSpacing, Action action)
    {
        _requiredClicks = requiredClicks;
        _maxClickSpacing = maxClickSpacing;
        _action = action;
    }

    public void Click()
    {
        var now = DateTime.Now;

        if (_clickStreak == 0)
        {
            //first click
            _clickStreak++;
            _lastClickedAt = now;
            return;
        }

        //reset if clicked too late
        if (now - _lastClickedAt > _maxClickSpacing)
        {
            _clickStreak = 1;
            _lastClickedAt = now;
            return;
        }

        //add
        _clickStreak++;
        _lastClickedAt = now;

        //invoke action and reset streak if enough clicks
        if (_clickStreak >= _requiredClicks)
        {
            _action?.Invoke();
            _clickStreak = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using it like this:

```cs
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace MyApp01;

public partial class MainWindow : Window 
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        //setup the click streak machine so the user has to click 5 times (each click within 400ms of the last one) to trigger the DoSomething method
        var clickStreakMachine = new ClickStreakMachine(5, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(400), () => DoSomething());

        var label = new Label();
        label.MouseLeftButtonDown += clickStreakMachine.Click();
    }
}
```